# Help with checking if a new puzzle is easy or hard

Tags: riddle

I created this puzzle for a Dungeons and Dragons quest and wanted to know if it is too easy (or hard) and I'll accept any help with the wording itself.

Here it goes:

"The pincers talked at the edge of the meadow
Balance was kept in the great tree's shadow
A bowl and its inhabitants were watching
What the twins and the lamb were setting
To surprise the one with horns that slept
If the king had already left
And the archer was preparing a trap
Who was resting in the maiden's lap?"

Comment: Is it a baby? If so, the last line led me to this conclusion.

Comment: No. All the entities in the riddle are associated, but only one is not mentioned in any way. That's the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer

> I recognize some signs of zodiac

For example

The pincers talked at the edge of the meadow

> Scorpius and Cancer

Balance was kept in the great tree's shadow

> Libra

A bowl and its contents were watching

> Aquarius + Pices

What the twins and the lamb were setting

> Gemini and Ares

To surprise the horns that slept

> Taurus

If the king had already left

> Leo

And the archer was preparing a trap

> Saggitarius

Who was resting in the maiden's lap?"

> Virgo

**And the answer is:**

> The one that is left out is **Capricorn**

Comment: The basic idea is right, but you've limited to think of only one entity in some lines. If the pincers were talking, there had to be more than one there. Same with the bowl and its contents. Any help in conveying those ideas?

Comment: I would, but at the moment I don't have enough time to search for all signs of zodiac I just named those that I could from top of my head. I will find the answer eventually.

Comment: @Zikato Pisces should be the bowl's (Aquarius) content I believe. Just a thought.

Comment: And Cancer has pincers as well

Comment: I updated the original post to specify the only one with horns was sleeping. Regardless, your thinking was spot on, so I'll check it as correct and say here that my original answer is Capricorn

Answer (score 1):

My best guess: Is it

> the fish

The clues are:

> the signs of the zodiac.

i.e.

> Pincers = Cancer & Scorpio, Balance = Libra, A bowl and it's contents = Aquarius, Twins = Gemini, lamb = Aries, Horns = Capricorn & Taurus, King = Leo, Archer = Sagittarius, Maiden = Virgo, so the only one not mentioned = Pisces.

Comment: You had most of it right, but the the bowl and its contents are separate entities, while only 1 entity with horns is sleeping. Any idea how I could tweak the text to show those diferences?

Comment: _The bowl and its inhabitants_ perhaps? _Horns_ could have covered three of them really. You need some other idea there.

Comment: Marked the other answer as correct, but gave you a +1 because your thinking was spot on but my wording was flawed.